# Remove the number fields from product URLs in Prestashop 1.7

Tags: url, overriding, seo, prestashop

The URLs of the product pages which have combination items contain a number next to it, such as this example below
https://example.com/nut-butters/4-103-natural-peanut-butter.html

I would like to know what are the overrides that need to be made in order to remove those 2 numbers from the URL
This is on Prestashop 1.7.7.5